# How can I customize new mail notification in alpine?

Tags: email, alpine-mail

I use alpine as my primary mail reader.  While I spend most of my day in the terminal or Emacs, it would still be nice to get pretty notification of new mail using notify-bin.  Is there any way I can configure alpine to run a custom command when new mail is received?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is "NewMail FIFO Path" configuration option in alpine. Quoting the help:

> You may have Alpine create a FIFO
>   special file (also called a named
>   pipe) where it will send a one-line
>   message each time a new message is
>   received in the current folder, the
>   INBOX, or any open Stayopen Folders.
>   To protect against two different
>   Alpines both writing to the same FIFO,
>   Alpine will only create the FIFO and
>   write to it if it doesn't already
>   exist.

So, I set the option to '/tmp/alpine.fifo', and wrote simple utility to read messages from the FIFO and invoke 'notify-send':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define FIFO_NAME "/tmp/alpine.fifo"

int main(void)
{   
    char s[512];
    char cmd[512];
    int num;
    int fd = open(FIFO_NAME, O_RDONLY);
    do {
        if ((num = read(fd, s, 300)) == -1)
            perror("read");
        else {
            s[num] = '\0';
            sprintf(cmd, "notify-send -t 0 'New mail:' '%s'", s);
            system(cmd);
        }
    } while (num > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Save it to alpine-notifier.c, and compile with 'gcc alpine-notifier.c -o alpine-notifier' command. Start 'alpine-notifier' after alpine is started. Enjoy pop-up notifications.

Comment: nice solution :-)

Comment: Awesome.  I wrote a small shell script to do essentially the same thing.

Comment: @steven: I'd vote for it if you'd be kind enough to share it. :-)

Comment: Nevermind, I ended up writing one as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**:
I wasn't satisfied with my previous answer, so I improved the script a lot and made a [github repo](https://github.com/Malabarba/alpine-osd-notify) for it.

Now you don't have to start the script after starting alpine, the script will take care of everything for you. The core of the script is mostly the same (I only improved parsing a little):

```
#! /bin/bash
while read L; do
    n=$(($n + 1))  
    if [[ n -gt 3 ]]; then      
        name=`echo "$L"  | sed 's/  \+/\t/g;s/^\(+ \)\?\([^\t]*\)\t\([^\t]*\)[\t ].*/\2/'`
        subject=`echo "$L"  | sed 's/  \+/\t/g;s/^\([^\t]*\)\t\(Re: \?\)\?\([^\t]*\)[\t ].*/\3/'`
        box=`echo "$L"  | sed 's/  \+/\t/g;s/^\([^\t]*\)\t\([^\t]*\)[\t ]\([^\t]*\).*/\3/'`
        notify-send -t 10000 $iconcommand "Mail from $name" "$subject\n-\nIn your $box."
    fi
done < <(cat alpine.fifo)
```

The rest of it is a little large to post here, so anyone who's interested can just get it at the [repo](https://github.com/Malabarba/alpine-osd-notify).

Comment: Bruce, thanks for sharing the script! Now I know how to read and process messages from FIFO while keeping it open in shell. Could not figure it out while setting up a notifier for myself :)

Comment: @Linulin Cool. =) Unfortunately the filters I used for setting `content` and `name` are a little buggy in some cases., which is a little silly since they're the reason I posted the answer at all. =P

Comment: It is awesome to see shell used so well.  Thanks for posting it on github.  Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a specialized mail-notification tool like Gnubiff, mail-notification or kbiff?

Comment: I would like to use mail-notification to achieve something similar, however I cannot find any documentation on how to customize the mail-notification new-mail command.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to customize the "new mail notification" of alpine.

There is no such option mentioned in the [configuration documentation](http://www.washington.edu/alpine/tech-notes/config.html).

Also here is a [quote](http://mailman2.u.washington.edu/pipermail/alpine-info/2009-January/001572.html) from the mailinglist from Eduardo Chappa:

> > I've noticed that alpine gives a visual alert in gnome terminal by 
> >     flashing the screen, when a new mail arrives. Is there any way to 
> >     customise the alert, so that, for instance, it plays a sound or 
> >     something?
>
> [..]
>
> Alpine, as you can guess now,
>   will only beep. In Web Alpine it is
>   possible  to send a file to be played
>   (to the browser) for new mail
>   notification.  There is no such
>   feature in Unix, Mac or Windows
>   Alpine.

Your options are now:

- write a feature request to the [alpine-info mailinglist](http://www.washington.edu/alpine/alpine-info/)
- get the sources and write a patch
- use an external tool like [Mail Notification](http://www.nongnu.org/mailnotify/)

And to quote the developer of my favorit mail client:

> All mailclients suck...

:-)